# convert special characters to regular alphabet in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a search page for a bunch of menu items in my database which often contain special characters like `é` (as in sautéed), and so I want to convert both the search query and the database content to regular alphabets, and I'm having trouble. I'm using ISO-8859-1 so that special characters will display properly on the website, and I get the feeling this is hindering my attempts at conversion...

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

The search query is sent to search.php using the GET method, so the query "sautéed" will appear like this in the address bar:

```
search.php?q=saut%E9ed
```

This is the function I'm trying to build, that's not working:

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
function clean_str($a) {
    $fix = array('é' => 'e');
    $str = str_replace(array_keys($fix), array_values($fix), $a);
    return $str;
}
$fixed = clean_str($q); // currently has no effect
```

I'm tried using `%29` as the array key, as well as the HTML character code (`&#233;`). I've tried `utf8_encode($q);` to no avail. Other characters like `!` and `+` work fine in the clean_str() function, but not special alphabets like `é`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you might want to reconsider the way you're doing this, as has been suggested, I believe this will get you there.

```
function clean_str($a) {
    $fix = array('é' => 'e');
    $str = str_replace(array_keys($fix), array_values($fix), $a);
    return $str;
}
$fixed = clean_str(utf8_encode($_GET['q'])); // return an encoded utf8 string.
echo $fixed;
```

For more on `utf8_encode` see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php).

Comment: converting **é** to **e** is as nonsensical as converting it to **7**

Answer (score 1):

To wit, é *is* the regular alphabet in several languages =) While you're suggesting you would like to know how to covert the text to ASCII (which English speakers may consider 'regular') what you really should be doing is working with the modern web's most permissive encoding, which is UTF8.

That way, you will be able to accept input in any language, save it, process it, and serve it back up, without needing to normalise or ill-convert to another codepage.

Serve your pages with `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the source code, and an http content header to indicate UTF8 encoding, and things should go a lot smoother. (note that for the now defunct HTML 4.01 or XHTML 1/1.1 you will need to use the older meta tag syntax. Using those flavours for new projects is, however, very much not recommended)

Comment: When I do this, characters like é appear as ?. I need to be able to determine that if the menu says sautéed, and the user simply types sauteed, that it's a match, which means converting the character regardless, which is what I'm struggling with.

Comment: That's called normalisation, and there should be some libaries for it on PEAR to achieve that goal. That said, characters appearing as `?` will only occur if you're not sending the data in the same encoding as you *say* you're sending. So to work like most modern webpages, you need to send your data with a php header that says the content is UTF8, and a <meta> tag that declares the source code is UTF8, and then send actual UTF8 data (so your files are UTF8 files, and you connect to your database if you use it in UTF8 charset/names)